# git rebase multiple branches

Tags: git, git-rebase

I would like to simplify this Git history, which contains
several Git branches:

```
*   83bc4db      
|\  
| * 66c64f9      
| * 32c1a93      
| * 8b5fd0c      
| * 501454e      
| *   b316bac    
| |\  
| * | 6d8f409    
| * | ca9747a    
| * |   fa37e88  
| |\ \  
| * | | 97ce58e  
* | | | e56b9df  
* | | | 33441b7  
* | | | e5b2606  
* | | | dbb039e  
* | | | 68f3082  
* | | | 17774ea  
* | | | 1945fbd  
| |_|/  
|/| |   
* | | 8c3b38d    
| |/  
|/|   
* | d0aaef1      
|/  
* 08273d5        
* 2f8652a        
* 0e3d8df
```

into a single commit:

```
* XXXXXXX
* 08273d5        
* 2f8652a        
* 0e3d8df
```

I tried to rebase with:

```
git rebase -i 08273d5
```

Then modify the git-rebase-todo like this:

```
pick d0aaef1 
squash 8c3b38d
squash 1945fbd
squash 17774ea
squash 68f3082
squash dbb039e
squash e5b2606
squash 33441b7
squash e56b9df
squash 97ce58e
squash ca9747a
squash 6d8f409
squash 501454e
squash 8b5fd0c
squash 32c1a93
squash 66c64f9
```

Git says:

```
error: could not apply 97ce58e... merge done

When you have resolved this problem run "git rebase --continue".
If you would prefer to skip this patch, instead run "git rebase --skip".
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing run "git rebase --abort".

Could not apply 97ce58e... merge done
```

What are the Git command(s) to issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to check out commit 08273d5, then check out all the files from 83bc4db into the working directory, then create a new branch and commit the changes, i.e. (from the top-level directory)

```
git checkout 08273d5
git checkout 83bc4db -- .
git checkout -b newbranchname
git commit -m "Some message"
```

Comment: Thanks. The last command says: nothing to commit (working directory clean)

Comment: @user744629: What does `git diff 08273d5 83bc4db` show? If you check out `08273d5` and then check out the files from `83bc4db`, the changes between the two should be visible when you do a `git status` and should be staged for commit. In which directory are you running the second command? Is it the top of the repository?

Comment: git diff 08273d5 83bc4db shows a alot of things (2048 lines). You're, right, I wasn't in the top of the repository! It works now. 83bc4db is the 'develop' branch. How can I push 'newbranchname' into origin/develop?

Comment: Should I set 'newbranchname' to be the local tracking branch of 'origin/develop', instead of develop?

Comment: The easiest way technically would be to rename `develop` to something else, then rename your new branch to `develop` and do a force push to origin, i.e. `git push -f origin develop`. The usual caveats about rewriting history in a public repository may well be relevant here of course.

Comment: That's ok for the caveats about rewriting history in a public repo: origin/develop is 08273d5, thanks for the remind. I renamed branches and pushed (didn't need the -f), everything worked fine. Thanks alot for your precious explanations.